# What is another way to say "baby steps"?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to name a timeline of the American Revolution. The title has to be clever. I was thinking something like " Baby steps to America's Independence " but that was one of the examples soo... I need another way to say it......

Comment: You could reword the title and use "Evolving"

Comment: How about "Slouching Toward Philadelphia to Be Born"?

Comment: Vote to close it as there is neither example sentence nor any context. General reference and a request for naming something.

Answer (score 2):

How about 'inching'?

> intr. & tr.v. inched, **inch·ing**, inch·es
>   To move or cause to move slowly or by small degrees: *inching along through stalled traffic; inched the chair forward.*

[inching. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 11 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inching .]

So,

> Inching toward Independence: America's Infancy

The *In-* *In-* *In-* resonance of 'inching', 'independence' and 'infancy' is a bonus 'cleverness'.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider ***[ventures](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20ventures)***

> (plural noun) a risky or daring journey or undertaking

[Google Definition]

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venture) defines the verb form as ***to start to do something new or different that usually involves risk***

You could perhaps title it as **"Pioneering Ventures into America's Independence"**

(My usage is only a slight modification of the example given alongside Google's definition)